# Steps to cancel UILocalnotification in objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I want to cancel UILocalnotification. I have created a method called cancelNotification where i am cancelling the notification. However still i am receiving notification even after cancelling 
I heard in app delegate in few of the delegates method we need to cancel notification .Can anyone explain me where all to call cancel method ..If anyone can help me out it would be great

```
   -(UILocalNotification *)scheduleNotification :(int)remedyID
        {
           NSString *descriptionBody;

           NSInteger frequency;

          UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

            NSLog(@"%d",remedyID);

            descriptionBody =[[self remedyDetailsForRemedyID:remedyID] objectForKey:@"RemedyTxtDic"];
            frequency = [[[self remedyDetailsForRemedyID:remedyID] objectForKey:@"RemedyFrequency"]intValue];

            NSArray *notificationFireDates = [self fireDatesForFrequency:frequency];

            for (NSDate *fireDate in notificationFireDates)
            {
                    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


                    notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
                    notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithString:descriptionBody];
                    notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
                    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

                    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

                    notif.fireDate = fireDate;

                    NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:notif.alertBody,                                         @"kRemindMeNotificationDataKey",  [NSNumber numberWithInt:remedyID],kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey,
                                              nil];

                    notif.userInfo = userDict;

                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
                }

                return notif;

    }

 - (void)cancelNotification:(int)remedyId
    {
    NSArray *notifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    NSLog(@"Cancelling... Before %d",[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]count]);

      for (UILocalNotification *notification in notifications)
      {

      int notifRemedyId = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"kRemindMeNotificationRemedyIDKey"]intValue];  // I change the key value

        NSLog(@"remedyID  : %d",remedyId);
        NSLog(@"notifyId : %d",notifRemedyId);
        if (remedyId == notifRemedyId) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
          }
       }

    NSLog(@"Cancelling... After %d",[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]count]);

     }
```

Comment: put a break point when you are cancelling the notification if its getting called or not.

Comment: Do you want to cancell all notification ? What is the output of those NSlog's ?

Comment: NSLog are showing correct values .. i wanted to know whether do i have to update in app delegates ?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];`

**just copy it** under the method didLaunchWithOptions or viewDidLoad or even on your next UILocalNotification code.

I believe that's what you mean in the delegate? if you call this method after the app launches  it will cancel all of your previous local notifications.

Comment: see when i add a notification to fire at particular time ..and when the user closes the app and relaunches the notification should fire ..that is why i am not calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` in viewdidload or appdelegate.

MY question is do uilocalnotiification fired from the app or from the device and if i cancel a notification will it get fired later ?

Comment: @raptor I'm not sure but I think if it's a `repeat interval` then it's from the device because it gets scheduled right after the `firedate` trigger. and if you cancel the notification it will not fire unless you reschedule it again.

Comment: @user1949873.....the notification is still firing even after i cancel the notification ...

Comment: Do i have to use `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:notificationID object:nil];` to cancel notification ?

Comment: No! That line of code is for NSNotification center used internally to send a signal when value changed between different classes or methods which is very different different from UILocalNotification used as an UIAlertView but in the background.

Comment: If it's still firing, make sure you are not scheduling new notifications after canceling the old ones.

Comment: no i am not scheduling new notifications ... do i have to use NSNotification to cancel any uilocalnotification?

Comment: @raptor Not at all! Try to copy the same code in my answer to the method didEnterBackground. Hope it works this time.

Comment: In my program the notification is fired for 3 times a day (Morning , afternoon , evening) when i cancel a notification say after morning the notification is not fired for rest of the day (this is the way i want it to perform) ...but the notification is getting fired the next day (morning) ..

Comment: What could be happening is when your notifications are cancelled you reopen your app that day and your notifications get rescheduled again!you need to figure out what makes reschedule and cancel it or post your code and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't really figure out what could be wrong. but I see that you are only canceling one notification not all of them: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];` that might be the fault you are having is not canceling the exact notification you are firing. Good Luck.